# Wordpress change HTML content of :after element for specific post category

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress site and I would like to select and change the content of a `:after` pseudo element ONLY in posts with a specific category tag.

My pseudo-code would go something like this:

```
- get the post category
- if post category == 'myCategory'
    .myElement:after{
       content: "new content here";
    }
```

I found the below code on another post and tried to adapt it to my use but with no luck.

```
function change_next_button(){
  $cat = get_the_category();

  if ( ! empty( $cat ) ) {
    $cat_name = $cat[0]->name;

    switch ($cat_name) {
      case 'nyhet':
        document.getElementsByClassName("button:after").style.content="next article";
        break;
    }
  } 
}
```

Much appreciated if anyone could help out with a solution

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements with JavaScript/jQuery as they aren't a part of the DOM.

What you can do is add a class in your case and do your styling on the stylesheet.

```
switch ($cat_name) {
  case 'nyhet':
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.querySelector(".yourbutton").classList.add("newclass");'</script>
    break;
}
```

Then in your stylesheet;

```
.newclass::after {
  /* Your new styles */
  /* You may need to use !important - I don't know your CSS structure. */
 }
```

Comment: Abdul, thanks for your answer,

Everything seems to work, except the line where I change the class:
'document.querySelector('yourelement').classList.add('newclass');

This line gives me the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function querySelector() in 
    /homepages

Comment: It's because your code is php. What I posted is JavaScript. I'll update the answer.